# What is the purpose of "Apply Rules" in mail?

Tags: mail.app, email

The Mail client (that comes with Mac OS X) has an "Apply Rules" menu option, but I don't see any option to create a rule like most other mail clients have. Two part question, what rules does the "Apply Rules" menu option apply, and how do I define new rules in Mail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a rule in Mail, open Mail preferences (**Mail > Preferences…** or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) and go to the Rules pane.

[image: Preferences]

The Apply Rules function applies to all rules whose "Active" checkbox is ticked.

[image]